# How can I manage repositories for plugins development?

Tags: svn, plugins

Say you have an application X and you want to develop plugins A, B and C.

The application can live without the plugins but plugins doesn't work without the application.

Also you want to improve application X.

So you would need repos for:

- X
- A
- B
- C
- Possible branches for X
- Possible branches for each plugin

The key here is that you need code X for plugins but the repo should have only the plugin code.

My interest is in develop those plugins and publish the repositories of the plugins but I would like to have the whole code in a place so I can create projects with my IDE.

I'm using SVN!

Comment: Are you aware of svn:externals? See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html and http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html. As far as I understand that's what you look for.

Comment: I wasn't aware. I just read it and I'm still thinking. My solution would be: create a new repository for each plugin and one for my main project. In the main project, add externals for the plugins so they are fetched from the corresponding trunk in the plugin repository. When I want to update a plugin (since I need the code of the main project), I create a new branch in the main project and when it's ready I commit the plugin folder to the trunk of its repository?? Not sure if that will work